# AbcPdf in ASP.NET MVC using C# causes error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, abcpdf

I want to convert HTML to PDF in ASP.NET MVC. I am using Abcpdf converter. I have tried following code but I get an error

> Unable to render HTML. Unable to load page. (HTTP 403)

Every time I run this line causes the error

```
theID = theDoc.AddImageUrl("http://www.yahoo.com/");
```

My complete code:

```
Doc theDoc = new Doc();
theDoc.Rect.Inset(72, 144);

theDoc.HtmlOptions.Engine = EngineType.MSHtml;
theDoc.HtmlOptions.UseScript = true;
theDoc.HtmlOptions.Media = MediaType.Print; 

theDoc.HtmlOptions.InitialWidth = 800; 
theDoc.Page = theDoc.AddPage();

int theID;
theID = theDoc.AddImageUrl("http://www.yahoo.com/");

while (true) {
    theDoc.FrameRect(); // add a black border

    if (!theDoc.Chainable(theID))
        break;

    theDoc.Page = theDoc.AddPage();
    theID = theDoc.AddImageToChain(theID);
}

for (int i = 1; i <= theDoc.PageCount; i++) {
    theDoc.PageNumber = i;
    theDoc.Flatten();
}

theDoc.Save(Server.MapPath("pagedhtml.pdf"));
theDoc.Clear();
```

Comment: What is the error message that is shown?

Comment: Unable to render HTML. Unable to load page. (HTTP 403)

Comment: Yes that is shown in the browser but what is shown in Visual Studio, you will get a specific exception like `NullReference` or similar.

Comment: Is `http://www.yahoo.com/` the actually URL you are trying to use? As `http://www.yahoo.com/` is not going to be an image.

Comment: Yes , then what can i do for convert html to pdf

Comment: @SubhashTripathi that's a) a completely different question and b) a very broad question itself. If you want to convert HTML to PDF, first *download* that HTML  and then convert it using a library. You'll find a *lot* of duplicate questions for either question. Trying code at random hoping it will work isn't going to help